# regex to define the captured groups in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry if the title is a little bit ambiguous..

I have 2 input fields in my HTML.

One field takes a regex expression, field that takes a sentence, field that takes a rule and last field that shows a result of the regex applied to that sentence based on the rule.

Example :-

```
1) regex -> "(\d+)\.(\d{3})"
2) sentence -> "23.667"
3) rule -> "I have got $1 and $2"
4) Result fields should be " I have got 23 and 667 ".
```

It's okay I did that and now I can see the result.

However, let's say that the rule was `"I have got $1 and $4"`

this is an error since we have 2 captured groups in the regex and I try to display the 4th captured group. I succeeded in doing such a regex. But if I had `"I have got $1 and $$4"` this is not an error since I should display in that case `" I have got 23 and $4 "`.

So I'm trying to do a regex that if it reads a "$" + a number bigger than the captured groups in my regex, it throws an error BUT if we had double "$", it does not throw the error..

So in my validator I had something like" assuming I have a maximum of 9 groups to capture in my regex".

```
new RegExp("[^\\$]\\$["+groups+"-9]","gi")
return (rule.match(myReg) || []).length>groups;
```

I just want my regex to detect if we have $2 for example but doesn't detect $$2..

Any hint?

Comment: why do you say that `$4` is an error trying with different javascript engines gives `$4`

Comment: I know it is not an error in Javascript, it's just the app I'm developing I want to display the error css. 

What matters for me is that I skip when I see $$4, I can't write the regex to skip the double $$, My regex captures $"$4" I don't want that.

Comment: maybe something like `(?:^|[^$])`, because of lack of lookbehinds in javascript engines

Comment: does not detect the single $

Comment: i meant `"(?:^|[^$])\\$`..`"`